# How do I use jinja for conditional css classes?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm making a flask application that displays pizzas and their ingredients using python and jinja. I want to represent veg ingredients as green circles and meat ingredients as red circles.

I have a pizza collection, and an ingredients collection. I want to compare toppings in the pizza collection, to ingredients properties in the ingredients collection.

I've tried using jinja to loop through toppings in the pizza collection, nesting a loop so that if any of the toppings match those in the ingredients then it should change which class is applied to aan icon.

A document in the pizzas collection:

```
_id:5d506eed1c9d4400000a4254
pizza_name:"vegetairian supreme"
pizza_code:"vs"
sauce_type:"pizza"
cheese_type:"mozzarella"
toppings:Array
0:"onions"
1:"mushrooms"
2:"peppers"
3:"sweetcorn"
4:"tomatoes"
allergens:""
is_veg:true
```

A document in the ingredients collection:

```
_id:5d506d341c9d4400000a4238
topping:"bacon"
is_meat:true
```

My code to display pizzas:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    {% for pizza in pizzas %}
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="collection with-header">
            <li class="collection-header">
                <h4>{{ pizza.pizza_name }}</h4>
            </li>
            {% for topping in pizza.toppings %}
            <li class="collection-item">
                {% for ing in ingredients %}
                    {% if ing.topping == topping %}
                        {% if ing.is_meat == True %}
                            <i class="meat tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping}}
                        {% elif ing.is_meat == False %}
                            <i class="veg tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping}}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %} 
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[The current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTTV2.png)

If I just do:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for pizza in pizzas %}
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="collection with-header">
            <li class="collection-header">
                <h4>{{ pizza.pizza_name }}</h4>
            </li>
            {% for topping in pizza.toppings %}
            <li class="collection-item">
                <i class="meat tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I will get a list of the toppings for each pizza with a black circle beside each, so I'm on the right track, I think!

CSS:
`style.css`

```
.meat{
    color:red;
}

.veg{
    color:red;
}
```

Other styles are from [materialize](https://materializecss.com)

Current html output:

```
<div class="card">
        <ul class="collection with-header">
            <li class="collection-header">
                <h4>vegetairian supreme</h4>
            </li>

            <li class="collection-item">























                            <i class="veg tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>onions



















            </li>

            <li class="collection-item">

            </li>

            <li class="collection-item">

            </li>

            <li class="collection-item">

            </li>

            <li class="collection-item">

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.  In your last code block, you don't do anything with CSS classes and you have a stray `{{items}}` that I don't think should be there.  Perhaps you can give example output of what you really want?

Comment: Should it be `if items.is_meat` instead of just `if is_meat`? I think you're using the `for` loops and then not using the item in each iteration, just using some value that doesn't exist

Comment: FWIW, you could do something like `<i class="{{ 'meat' if items.is_meat else 'veg' }} tiny material-icons>`.

Comment: I see... `items` is a bad name... it should probably have been either `topping` or `item`.

Comment: I agree, items is not the best name, I've changed that to `topping`.
What I'm looking to ouput is:
`(green circle) onions (green circle) mushrooms (red circle) beef`

Comment: Did you get this to work without Jinja involved?  I don't think it's Jinja that's the issue... it's the styling.  What does your css look like?  Can you include that in your post?

Comment: I've updated the code to show some changes I've made from suggestions, and added the CSS. Forgot to state that I am using css from [materialize](https://materializecss.com)

Comment: I've found at least one reason why I'm having issues. In my app.py while I have: ```@app.route('/get_pizzas')
def get_pizzas():
    return render_template("pizzas.html", pizzas=mongo.db.pizzas.find(), ingredients=mongo.db.ingredients.find())```
This returns pizzas to pizzas.html but not ingredients.

Comment: I'm not sure that's your problem.  As far as I can tell, your code is doing nothing with `ingredients`.  You are expecting each pizza to contain a list of toppings though.  It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve, what the final output should look like, and what you are actually seeing (html output preferable, so we can see what your code is producing).

Comment: It would also be good to see what the result of `mongo.db.pizzas.find()` actually looks like too. :-)

Comment: Which icon are you trying to use? I have a hunch that your icon use is not quite right for that library. Also, I would recommend you hand code example output for yourself in plain HTML/CSS and make sure it works as expected before trying to dynamically generate it.

Comment: What does an ingredient look like?  Should you be comparing it differently?  Something like `topping == ing.name` or the like?  It looks like `topping == ing` is not matching anything.

Comment: So it looks like you should be comparing `topping` to `ing.topping`.  Instead of `{% if ing == topping %}` check `{% if ing.topping == topping %}`.

Comment: BTW, we don't get notification on your comments to the post unless you tag us with @username. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister `{% if ing.topping == topping %}` works a bit better, but only works for the first topping in the first pizza. I think it's only reading the data for `ing in ingredients` once.

Comment: Oh, that might be.  If what is being returned is an iterable versus a list or tuple (something that is fully instantiated), then you can only iterate through it once.  You should convert the result of mongo.db.ingredients.find() to a list.  That said, there’s probably a better and more efficient way of doing this, such as putting the name of all meat ingredients into a set and checking to see if the topping is in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what I did to make it work.

On mongo I tidied things up:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d5353ee1c9d440000cb278e"},"meats":["bacon","beef","roast chicken","tandoori chicken","ham","meatballs","pepperoni","chorizo","sausage"]}
```

Then in my app.py I made dictionaries for each ingredient to be reuseable:

```
meats = mongo.db.ingredients.find_one({'meats' : {'$exists': True}})
vegs = mongo.db.ingredients.find_one({'vegs' : {'$exists': True}})
sauces = mongo.db.ingredients.find_one({'sauces' : {'$exists': True}})
cheeses = mongo.db.ingredients.find_one({'cheeses' : {'$exists': True}})

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/get_pizzas')
def get_pizzas():
    return render_template("pizzas.html",
                           pizzas=mongo.db.pizzas.find(), 
                           meats = meats,
                           vegs = vegs,
                           sauces = sauces,
                           cheeses = cheeses)
```

Then to display the pizzas with the conditionaly classes I done:

```
    <div class="row ">
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="collection with-header">
                <li class="collection-header">
                    <h4>{{ pizza.pizza_name.capitalize() }}</h4>
                </li>
                <li class="collection-item">
                    <i class="{{pizza.sauce_type}} tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{pizza.sauce_type.capitalize()}}
                </li>
                <li class="collection-item">
                    <i class="cheese tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{pizza.cheese_type.capitalize()}}
                </li>
                {% for topping in pizza.toppings %}
                    {% for veg in vegs.vegs %}
                        {% if veg == topping %}
                            <li class="collection-item">
                                <i class="veg tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping.capitalize()}}
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for meat in meats.meats %}
                        {% if meat == topping %}
                            <li class="collection-item">
                                <i class="meat tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping.capitalize()}}
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And now it works! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So after all the back and forth, I think the question is probably a bit off at this point since there were several factors involved.

The first issue was that the comparison between topping and ingredient was off.  You had `{% if ing == topping %}` but it really needed to be `{% if ing.topping == topping %}` since an ingredient was actually a document.

After more discussion, it appears there is another issue in this function:

```py
@app.route('/get_pizzas')
def get_pizzas():
    return render_template("pizzas.html",
                           pizzas=mongo.db.pizzas.find(), 
                           ingredients=mongo.db.ingredients.find())
```

It appears that mongo is returning a [Cursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) which is iterable.  This also means that you can only loop through it once.  This also brings up another issue in that the mechanism used to determine whether a topping is a meat or not is rather inefficient.  You have run through all N toppings of the pizza, and for each topping run through all M ingredients, making it an O(N*M) operation.  Instead, you could do something like this:

```py
@app.route('/get_pizzas')
def get_pizzas():
    meats = set(ing.topping for ing in mongo.db.ingredients.find() if ing['is_meat'])
    return render_template("pizzas.html",
                           pizzas=mongo.db.pizzas.find(), 
                           meats=meats)
```

Here, we create a set containing the names of all ingredients that are meats so we can do a simple check to see if a topping is a meat.  Then in your template, you can do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
    {% for pizza in pizzas %}
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="collection with-header">
            <li class="collection-header">
                <h4>{{ pizza.pizza_name }}</h4>
            </li>
            {% for topping in pizza.toppings %}
            <li class="collection-item">
                <i class="{{ 'meat' if topping in meats else 'veg' }} tiny material-icons">brightness_1</i>{{topping}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The magic is here: `{{ 'meat' if topping in meats else 'veg' }}`.  This is the check to see if a topping is a meat and it's doing so by checking to see if the topping is in the `meats` set.  This reduces the look up for whether a topping is a meat to O(1) making the whole algorithm O(N), which is what it should be.  The only catch here is that you could be potentially creating a large set if you had a large number of ingredients.  It might be better to structure your backend differently to avoid that problem in the future.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put into helping me. Doing the above gives an error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_meat'`. However this does give me some food for thought to tackle this again in the morning. I agree I should set up the ingredients collection a bit differently like `'veg': 'onions', 'peppers'` and `'meat': 'beef', 'bacon'`. Again thank you.

Comment: Updated the code.  I wasn't sure if you got dictionaries, named tuples, or something else back from mongo.  But the error answers the question.  The code should be fixed now. :-)  And you're welcome.  It can be frustrating to debug things when there are several issues playing together.  I'm happy I could help!